# Can I direct wire an under the counter light into the LOAD terminals of a kitchen GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have two kitchen outlets on a 20 amp breaker.  I got some IKEA under cabinet lights and I am wondering if I can use the other LOAD slots for the light.

Comment: Is this in the USA or another country?  Most under cabinet lights no longer have the once ubiquitous convenience outlet, if yours does it might effect the answer.

Comment: "Can I use the mysterious and warning-label-covered LOAD terminals because I don't know how to pigtail?" All due respect the right answer is learn how to pigtail.  I pigtail 90% of my receptacles. Because it is easier to fit when working in awkward positions.

Answer (score 1):

### Nope -- kitchen receptacle circuits need to stick to kitchen receptacles

You'll have to run the lights on a different circuit to meet Code, as putting lighting on a kitchen small appliance branch circuit violates NEC 210.52(B) (in particular, 210.52(B)(2)).  Note that "outlet" by itself in the NEC means *any* place where power is supplied to a device (whether it's a luminaire, a receptacle, or a piece of hardwired equipment), not just receptacles.

> **(B) Small Appliances.**
>
> **(1) Receptacle Outlets Served.** In the kitchen, pantry,
>   breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling
>   unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch
>   circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and
>   floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all counter-top outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for
>   refrigeration equipment.
>
> *Exception No.1: In addition to the required receptacles
>   specified by 210.52, switched receptacles supplied from a
>   general-purpose branch circuit as defined in 210.70(A)(1),
>   Exception No.1, shall be permitted.*
>
> *Exception No.2: The receptacle outlet for refrigeration
>   equipment shall be permitted to be supplied from an individual branch circuit rated 15 amperes or greater.*
>
> **(2) No Other Outlets.** The two or more small-appliance
>   branch circuits specified in 210.52(B)(1) shall have no
>   other outlets.
>
> *Exception No. 1: A receptacle installed solely for the electrical supply to and support of an electric clock in any of
>   the rooms specified in 210.52(B)(1).*
>
> *Exception No.2: Receptacles installed to provide power
>   for supplemental equipment and lighting on gas-fired
>   ranges, ovens, or counter-mounted cooking units.*

Comment: In NEC parlance,  "outlet" is any supply to any device i.e. Hardwired, not just receptacles.